# objetos S3 , S4 en R

Tags: r

Soy usuario de R desde ya hace un tiempo, pero principalmente dentro del campo de la estadistica, aunque hace poco he tenido la ide ade adentrarme en el mundo de la programacion, he estado revisando algunos topicos y demás, pero en la parte de OOP S3 y S4 no entiendo bien cual es la diferencia entre ambas y sobretodo todo cual me recomiendan (ventajas y desventajas) ademas de cual presenta mejores posibilidades de integrar con otros lenguajes como python

Gracias por anticipado

Comment: Bienvenido por favor lee [ask], las preguntas amplias y basadas en opiniones terminan cerradas

Answer (score 1):

Voy a tratar de centrarme en la parte de tu pregunta que no es opinable, la de las diferencias en los modelos **S3** y **S4**. Por empezar hay que mencionar que R, tiene o ha tenido varias intentos de adopción del modelo **OOP**, con distinto éxito, que yo contabilice hubo/hay al menos 9 o 10 modelos distintos, algunos experimentales otros ya deprecados. Los modelos **S3** y **S4** son lo más antiguos y más conocidos, de hecho son "heredados" del lenguaje madre **S**. veamos:

- **S3**: Nace con la versión 3 de **S**. Es el modelo más simple, pero también el más extendido, es el único modelo de **OOP** que usan una enorme cantidad de funciones del paquete base de R. Esta básicamente centrado en la "sobrecarga" de funciones. Esto es algo que se usa todo el tiempo, por ejemplo `summary()` o `print()` entre muchísimas, son en realidad funciones genéricas **S3** que resuelven el método según el objeto que reciben. Este modelo, no maneja el concepto de Clase tradicional con propiedades y métodos, la clase es simplemente un identificador, una cadena que se asocia como atributo de cualquier objeto ya existente. Además de la sobrecarga, tiene un esquema muy simple de herencia. La principal ventaja de este modelo es que es muy simple y consistente con R base, si necesitas crear una nueva clase de objeto, puedes desarrollar toda una serie de métodos consistentes con las funciones ya existentes de R, y así permitir que el usuario final pueda hacer `summary(tu_objeto_nuevo)` o `mean(tu_objeto_nuevo)`.
- **S4**: Como es de suponer nace con la versión 4 de **S**, la última versión existente. R adopta este modelo igual que el **S3**. A diferencia del modelo anterior, dónde cualquier objeto, puede asociarse de manera libre a cualquier clase, **S4** es algo más estricto, posee una función `setClass()` que permite definir de manera más estricta las propiedades (slots) que tiene una clase, y ahora sí hay que instanciar el objeto mediante una función `new()`, los métodos, como en el modelo anterior , se crean de manera independiente a la definición de la clase. Este es el paradigma que se usa principalmente en los paquetes del proyecto [bioconductor](https://www.bioconductor.org/), sin embargo no es el modelo más usado en los paquetes de CRAN. La ventaja que tiene, es que ahora sí hay un poco más del concepto de clase, y los objetos pueden contener propiedades.

Comentarios extra:

- Si tu objetivo final es el análisis de datos, es muy poco probable que la **OOP** te pueda aportar algo, el paradigama funcional para esto es más que suficiente
- Ahora, si tu idea es desarrollar herramientas complejas, puede que una orientación a objetos eventualmente te reporte algún beneficio
- ¿Que modelo elegir? depende. **S3** al menos para cosas básicas que quieras integrar bien a R base, **S4**, en mi opinión si vas a construir paquetes bajo el ala del proyecto [bioconductor](https://www.bioconductor.org/), pero no mucho más.
- Si buscas una aproximación más clásica y completa a la **OOP**, deberías apuntar a los modelos más nuevos, casí con seguridad iría por el lado de [R6](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/r6.html).

Answer (score 0):

Si manejas bien el inglés también te puede servir leer el capítulo sobre programación orientada a objetos de "Advanced R" de Hadley Wickham. https://adv-r.hadley.nz/oo.html. Explica acerca de los tres principales modos de uso de la OOP en R y tiene un subcapítulo de comparaciones.

En concreto, respecto a tu pregunta, indica que el sistema R6 tiene mayor similitud con la forma en que python trata la OOP.